# echo $PATH shows $PATH

Tags: linux

On one of my systems, I have a strange situation. When I execute `env` on any machine the result looks like below:

```
[sup@vviesup07 ~ ]$ env |grep PATH
PATH=/usr/java/latest/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/sup/.local/bin:/home/sup/bin:/home/sup/.local/bin:/home/sup/bin
[sup@vviesup07 ~ ]$
```

But on one machine with one user, the result looks like:

```
[aut@vviesup09 ~ ]$ env |grep PATH
PATH=.:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin:$PATH
[aut@vviesup09 ~ ]$
```

As you see, PATH is not evaluated. It just displays $PATH instead of evaluating the variable.
What can be wrong here? Where can I look for the error?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like some command for updating `PATH` used a single-quote `'` instead of double quote `"` or no-quote:

```
PATH='.:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin:$PATH'
```

Replace it with a double-quote:

```
PATH=".:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin:$PATH"
```

To look for it, check [this question and answer about `PATH`](https://superuser.com/q/284342/889037).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I use no quotes at all:
export PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin:$PATH

Comment: You should debug it: now that you know which script gives you trouble, add e.g `echo $PATH` to it.